# Acumatica Is it possible to customize Business Logic on Dialog boxes (Related Items on Sales Orders Screen)?

Tags: dialog, acumatica

[image]I would like to define the prices of the related items at 0.
I also would like to prefilter the grid on the warehouse corresponding to the SoLine branch.

Changing the field attribute is not working. There's no change when testing the customization.
[image: define curyUnitPrice to 0]

Comment: Give a screenshot of what exactly dialog you want to modify please

Comment: It's 'Add Related Items' on 'Sales Orders' Screen (Cross Sell & Substitute Items), screenshot added.

Comment: understand, which Acumatica build you target, and how to make that button available in default sales demo. In my case I wasn't able to find that button readily available.